# input type search like Chat GPT search input with icon. input icon is not setting up in input

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, input

I have a input with icon like Chat GPT search input After some lines it's icon goes up I want fix it's in same position. this is my code. I want where it shows first if I add more lines same show its position and go to bottom side.
if anyone is interested please give me good Answer. Thanks in Advance!

html of the input

```
 <div class="chat-input-container">
    <div class="input-container" ng-class="{'scrollable': shouldShowScroll()}">
        <div contenteditable="true" class="input-field" ng-model="setSearchInputValue"
            ng-keypress="onKeyPress($event)"></div>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-disabled="setSearchInputValue.trim().length === 0">
            <md-icon md-font-icon="material-icons"
                ng-disabled="setSearchInputValue.trim().length === 0">send</md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </div>
```

js of the input

```
 $scope.shouldShowScroll = function () {
            var inputField = document.querySelector('.input-field');
            var lineHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(inputField).getPropertyValue('line-height'));
            var maxLines = 8; 
            return inputField.scrollHeight > lineHeight * maxLines;
        };
```

css of the input

```
    #input {
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    .bg-yellow {
        background-color: lightyellow;
    }

    .bg-green {
        background-color: #eafef6;
    }

    .chat-input-container {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 5px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 40%;
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-left: 450px;
        /* remove margin to use any where*/
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .input-container {
        flex: 1;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        max-height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        /* Align items to the start of the flex container */
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }

    .scrollable {
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .input-field {
        min-height: 25px;
        height: auto;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
        resize: none;
        width: 90%;
        line-height: 20px;
        white-space: webkit-nowrap;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        flex: 1;
    }

    md-button {
        bottom: 0;
        min-width: 40px;
        background-color: #0078D7;
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 6px;
        align-self: flex-end;
    }

    md-button md-icon {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    md-button:hover {
        background-color: #005A9E;
    }

    .md-button.md-icon-button {
        margin: 0 6px;
        height: 40px;
        min-width: 0;
        line-height: 24px;
        padding: 8px;
        width: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-left: 6px;
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
```

Comment: try to provide a more functioning example please. but try messing around with overflow-wrap. more likely a issue with flex, but that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have to try this one

```css
 textarea{
        overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    }

.form-group {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
}

#input {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%; /* Use 100% to fill the parent div */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and border in the width calculation */
}

.icon-user {
    position: absolute;
    right: 9px;
    top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.12/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   

            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea rows="4" cols="60" id="input" placeholder="متن ..."></textarea>
                <span class="icon-user">
                    <icon md-font-icon="material-icons">icon</icon>
                </span>
            </div>
```